# Do the words menorah and Torah have the same root in Hebrew?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hebrew, behaalotcha-parsha, menorah--in-temple

I'm studying the parashat Behaaloscha, the part where Aharon kindle de Menorah. I read that the meaning of Menorah has to do with 'Tora Study. I'm from Brazil where we speak Portuguese and the words Men(or)ah and T(or)ah seems to have the same root. Do they have the same hebrew root?

Comment: Klein has menorah from [Formed from נור (= to shine), with pref. מְ◌ and first suff. ◌ָה. cp. Aram. מְנַרְתָּא (= candlestick), Arab. manāra (= candlestick; lighthouse; tower of a mosque).] Torah is [Verbal n. of הוֹרָה (= he pointed out, instructed, taught), Hiph. of ירה.]

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned (I forget where, but it is a well known *vort*), that Torah has it's root both in hora'a (teaching) and Or (light). So it seems that your connection is correct.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if it would cite support for _or_ (light) being the root of _m'nora_.